# Unix:Bash:Script sits after using head command

Tags: bash, unix

I have a script that runs fine when I do not use the head command, but when I do use it and run the script, the script just sits as if it is waiting for a command to be inserted.

I am using head to try and limit the the lines of a file to 1000.

The file I am trying to limit is described in the path of the ${LOG} variable below. That file is where the results of the script are going to and the file is named based on what directory you are running the script for and the OS that is found.

Ex: ./test ex1

File will be named ex1-Linux-X.log.

I am using:

```
head -n1000 > filename
```

To try and limit the lines of output.

Here is some of my script to show where I am trying to use it.

```
STUID=$1
PATH=${PATH}\:.
TMPFILE=tempfile
GDIR=`pwd`
OSNAME=`uname -s`
LOG=${GDIR}/results/${STUID}-${OSNAME}-X.log
DATE=`date`



 make -s clean
rm -f ${LOG}
touch ${LOG}
head -n1000 > filename
```

If there needs to be more code to fully understand what is going on, just let me know.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: And what if there's less than 1000 lines in the input? How do you use the script? What's the input? A pipe? Redirection?

Comment: @Pileborg Well, I thought head just put a cap of 1000 lines on the file. That way if there were less than 1000 lines then it wouldn't matter.

Comment: With that argument the `head` command will stop at 1000 lines or an end-of-file. But if the input is a pipe there may be no end-of file if the write-end of the pipe is still open, which means the `head` command may block.

Comment: @Pileborg Ok, I understand that, that makes sense. Is there a concrete way in Bash to limit the amount of lines of output you want to a file?

Comment: Why are you trying to limit your log file to just 1000 lines?

Comment: @Schwern  For the script I have, when it runs and outputs the results into a file, it runs into a loop where the same output is printed out a couple thousand times, and rather than go through that I am trying to truncate it to 1000.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`head -n1000 > filename` says to read the first thousand lines *from STDIN* and output them to filename.  `head` will sit around waiting for you to type 1000 lines of input into the program.

If you just want to truncate a file to the first 1000 lines, `head` can do that, but you have to use a temp file.

```
head -n1000 ${LOG} > ${LOG}.tmp
mv ${LOG}.tmp ${LOG}
```

If you tried that in one step, the shell redirection (`> ${LOG}`) would truncate the log file before `head` read it.

This is not a good idea to do on an actively used log file, things may be writing to it and may continue to attempt to write to the *deleted log file*.  Instead, you'd use `truncate` to truncate the file at line 1000.  `truncate` works in bytes, so use `head` and `wc` to find out what byte the 1000th line is on.

```
truncate --size=`head -n1000 ${LOG} | wc -c` ${LOG}
```

Based on your code, I'm not sure what you actually want.  Your code deletes and recreates the log file, then calls `head` on the guaranteed to be empty log file.  Do you want a file that can *never* exceed 1000 lines?  Can't do that, not without messing with named pipes or some sort of filesystem event program, and you probably don't want to do that.

You probably want something like a [FIFO queue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIFO), as new log entries are added, old ones get thrown out.  Files are [LIFO, like a stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_%28abstract_data_type%29), you're adding new log entries at the end, and you're also removing them from the end.  If you limited your file to 1000 lines, you'd be throwing out *new* log lines.

Which comes to the next problem: 1000 lines is pretty small.  It's an inconsequential amount of disk space, maybe 80k?  A major event, the ones you most want logging for, can *easily* blow over 1000 lines of logging.  You might want to bump that up a bit.

Instead, use a log rotater.  This is a program that will periodically archive your logs into daily, hourly, weekly and monthly log files.  This way your log files remain small, its easier to find things, you never lose log information, and you can periodically backup and delete old logs.  It depends on what system you're using, [Debian has logrotate](https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/logrotate).

Another option is instead of writing the log yourself, use a logging server, such as [syslog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syslog) or a database.  The log server can manage the size of the log files.  This is probably overkill for a 1000 line log file.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but is there any way to truncate the output that goes to the log file, to a maximum of 1000 lines?

Comment: @user2419571 Yes.  Why? I ask because while it seems like it should be easy, it isn't, and the effort is best avoided if you don't need it. And which 1000?  The first 1000 or the last 1000?

Comment: @SchwernFor the script I have, when it runs and outputs the results into a file, it runs into a loop where the same output is printed out a couple thousand times, and rather than go through that I am trying to truncate it to the first 1000 lines. I can post more code if needed.

Comment: @user2419571 Can you fix the loop so it doesn't print the same thing out a couple thousand times?

Comment: No, because it is part of a test I am running. I read to use Ulimit, but I am not familiar with it so that is why I tried to use head. But, my understanding of head was wrong.

Comment: I updated with full script if that helps any. Again, I really appreciate your help.

Comment: @user2419571 What part of that is spitting out the repetitive information?  Why truncate it in the program, why not truncate it after the fact?  Or just read the first 1000 lines and ignore the rest?

Comment: Reading the first 1000 lines and ignoring the rest would work. I was trying to truncate it in the program because I believe that to be the easiest. That way, when the program was finished running, the results file was already truncated to the 1000 lines.

Comment: @user2419571 Using a pager like `less` to read the log file will make truncating unnecessary. Unlike a text editor, `less` will not read the whole file immediately, it will only read as much as you read.

Comment: That is a very good solution. Again, I thank you. I do not mean to bother you so much. Other than that, there isn't anything else I can use to truncate the file? The reason I ask now is because I came this far trying this route. I want to at least understand how I could do it for future reference or just for the know how because my solutions weren't right.

Comment: @user2419571 I've added two ways to truncate the file to my answer.

Comment: I don't mean to keep thanking you, but I really appreciate it. This is the most help I have ever received on this site. It means a lot and I have learned a lot more in the few minutes talking to you. Thank you again for all of your help and explanations. I have really learned a lot.

Answer (score 1):

head command is not supposed to be used for limiting the line goes to a file.

here is the manual for head command.

> HEAD(1)                   BSD General Commands Manual
>   HEAD(1)
>
> NAME
>        head -- display first lines of a file
>
> SYNOPSIS
>        head [-n count | -c bytes] [file ...]
>
> DESCRIPTION
>        This filter displays the first count lines or bytes of each of the specified files, or of the standard input if no files are spec-
>        ified.  If count is omitted it defaults to 10.
>
> ```
>  If more than a single file is specified, each file is preceded by a header consisting of the string ``==> XXX <=='' where ``XXX''
>  is the name of the file.
> ```
>
> EXIT STATUS
>        The head utility exits 0 on success, and >0 if an error occurs.
>
> SEE ALSO
>        tail(1)
>
> HISTORY
>        The head command appeared in PWB UNIX.
>
> BSD                              June 6, 1993
>   BSD (END)

Comment: Well poop, I definitely misunderstood that then. I guess this a question for another day but what would I use to limit the amount of lines to a file?

Comment: echo ${STUID} ${OSNAME} ${DATE} | head -n 1000 > ${LOG} can be used to limit max 1000 line in that one echo statement.